# Gmail email only decodes headers when I run it through base64 decoder

Tags: python-3.x, gmail, gmail-api, email

I am trying to decode a message from Gmail.  I am using the default get_message() function from the gmail api.  It looks like I am decoding the headers of the email, but even though I am running the text through the base 64 decoder, the body of the email is still returned un decoded.  Any help getting the body of the email to decode correctly would be greatly appreciated!  Below is the function I am using, and what the print function returns:

```
def get_message(service, user_id, msg_id):
    try:
        message = service.users().messages().get(userId=user_id, id=msg_id, format='raw').execute()
        msg_raw = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(message['raw'].encode('ASCII'))
        msg_str = email.message_from_bytes(msg_raw)
        content_types = msg_str.get_content_maintype()
        print(msg_str)
```

And here is part of what I get when i print msg_str:

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
From: xxxxxxxx@xxxx.com
To: xxxxxxx@gmail.com
Reply-To: no-reply@xxxxxxx.com
Date: Mon, 15 Jun 2020 18:04:52 +0000 (UTC)
Subject: Your subject line here
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
X-RCIS-Action: ALLOW
Message-ID: <gYVgv8UEScaE_tbOkDveNw@ismtpd0034p1las1.sendgrid.net>
X-SG-EID: Ap3vdjbPGAKcTGFw7Eo1svjoaFy5XYEjNVu77BufzmUAjCf6aYR+XSXjw7ibAUowXCb0UJhsslBkBD
 Ruoukd4gvMabp3XWN/UbzDiqaAoGCz/WCNdNf9x3D9APOKeFYrZrE8wSn7a0pyYGkWPxBrrKKrkODD
 L3t5+l5uf7hSLqOnT1Zo3YDJeczbtM7SGu//TGl3QRvFFmVAiKXmVN62sA==
X-Feedback-ID: 8340127:zoIy9G3JApamNWAibxpVx2fbkPkU9DYqDP9JHIkh0jc=:zoIy9G3JApamNWAibxpVx2fbkPkU9DYqDP9JHIkh0jc=:SG

PCFET0NUWVBFIGh0bWwgUFVCTElDICItLy93M2MvL2R0ZCB4aHRtbCAxLjAgdHJhbnNpdGlvbmFs
Ly9lbiIgImh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnL3RyL3hodG1sMS9kdGQveGh0bWwxLXRyYW5zaXRpb25h
bC5kdGQiPjxodG1sIHN0eWxlPSJtYXJnaW46IDA7cGFkZGluZzogMDtmb250LWZhbWlseTogJ0hl
bHZldGljYSBOZXVlJywgJ0hlbHZldGljYScsIEhlbHZldGljYSwgQXJpYWwsIHNhbnMtc2VyaWY7
Ym94LXNpemluZzogYm9yZGVyLWJveCIgeG1sbnM9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzE5OTkveGh0
bWwiPjxoZWFkIHN0eWxlPSJtYXJnaW46IDA7cGFkZGluZzogMDtmb250LWZhbWlseTogJ0hlbHZl
dGljYSBOZXVlJywgJ0hlbHZldGljYScsIEhlbHZldGljYSwgQXJpYWwsIHNhbnMtc2VyaWY7Ym94
```

Answer (score 1):

You are grabbing the `raw` field of the message returned by the API. This field is complete message bytes encoded as Base64 (which you are already decoding).

If you look at the headers of the decoded raw email, you will notice that:

```
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
```

Indicates that the body of the message is also Base64 encoded meaning that you will have to decode the body of the email anyway. Otherwise, you may have to dig into the `message['payload']` object to see if there is anything there.

Ideally, you would look at the `Content-Transfer-Encoding` in your program to figure out what to do with the body of the message. You might consider reading up on [RFC 1521](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1521.txt) for more info about specifying message bodies in email.

Comment: Thank you for this info. When I use the get_payload() I get the email body in bytes. I can then run that through the base64 decoder, and I get html returned, but the html is still in bytes, and I cannot decode it, because it has a ton of '\n' and other characters in there.

Comment: @Lzypenguin Are you decoding with the correct character set? I see you doing something with ASCII, but the headers indicate UTF-8.